# Can a mosquito bite on different parts of the body react differently?

Tags: insect-bites

I get a lot of mosquito bites and have noticed that how severe my reaction is depends on where on my body I got bit. I wonder if this is normal and why this occurs?

Comment: are you referring to your immediate reaction, or to how long before the bites heals?

Comment: @KateGregory immediate reaction, such as intensity of itchiness and the degree of swelling

Comment: Well, there is a different reaction of me (doesn't qualify as body though): I'd say that the closer to my hands, the more lethal it is for the mosquito. ;)